# Can the page table be paged out?

Tags: operating-system, virtual-memory

According to my understanding it shouldn't be, since it's in kernel space and kernel space is non pageable. But with 64 bit address space I don't see how it can hold the full page table since it would be prohibitively large. Any ideas on how this achieved?

Also I guess even holding it on disk fully would take a lot of space. Since most of the VM space would be unused is there way to limit the page table to contain only used VM address ranges?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page table is actually a tree: it consists of multiple child tables. The head (root) table stores pointers to child tables, the child tables may also store the pointers to their child tables, and so on (the last table in chain stores the actual page table entry, of course). As the most memory in 64-bit address space is unused, it is not necessary to actually allocate memory for all the tables. The root table just sets most of its pointers to null.

On x86_64, there are 4-5 levels of such indirection.

Comment: I believe that would be true. However this hierarchical design gave rise to another question in my mind. So these addresses contained in top level page tables, are they virtual? If so that would lead to bit of a chicken egg problem trying to resolve a one virtual address leading to additional lookups?

Comment: All the pointers in those tables use physical addressing (they are not virtual)

Answer (score 2):

The page table only needs to hold some subset of the pages that are available. There is no rule that it be complete. When an attempt is made to access a virtual address not mapped by the page table, the kernel is invoked. It can then put that mapping into the page table, removing other mappings that haven't been used recently if desired.

The OS is free to keep every possible mapping that a process might access in the page tables if it wants. Alternatively, it can keep only those recently used if it would prefer that arrangement.

Comment: I was under the impression the page table lookup was indexed. (e.g: Add the index derived from higher order bits in the virtual address to the Page Table Base Register address to get to the page table entry). But using given the scheme it would require going through whole table to check whether the mapping is present or not as I understood.

Comment: I came across the inverted page table design which is bit similar to is what you referring to. I guess some form of hashing would be used to speed up the lookup.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Quote from wiki - [page table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_table)

> It was mentioned that creating a page table structure that contained mappings for every virtual page in the virtual address space could end up being wasteful. **But, we can get around the excessive space concerns by putting the page table in virtual memory, and letting the virtual memory system manage the memory for the page table.**
>
> However, **part of this linear page table structure must always stay resident in physical memory**, in order to prevent against circular page faults, that look for a key part of the page table that is not present in the page table, which is not present in the page table, etc.